# stuck on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There was a glitch on minecraft where there was a massive hole and I could see the stuff underneath. Then it pushed me in and now I cant get back out because I'm falling continuously. Once I hit bedrock, I start all over again.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The blocks are there, they are just not getting displayed.

You can either log out and back in, the chunk (the 16x16 blocks part thats missing) will reload then.

Or you can just go / jump your way back to the visible part. Remember, the blocks are there, they are just not getting displayed. There might be a tree in your way or another block blocking your way. It might look like you´re lagging, jumping can help to fix the "rubberbanding movement"

Comment: In newer versions, the shortcut F3+A will reload chunks around you, hopefully fixing the missing chunk issue without the need to relog.

Comment: Using the teleport command (`/tp`) is another option, if you can't find your way out.

Comment: He's using an old beta, which doesn't have /tp

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing with someone else you can type

```
/tp {target player} {destanation player}
```

I know about this because I got myself stuck in a glitch too.